# Запуск процесса на нескольких ядрах

Tags: linux

У меня есть 2 серверных Xeon процессора с 32  ядрами  и установленной Linux Ubuntu 16.04. У меня есть питоновский скрипт,при запуске скрипта он выполняется на 1 ядре и это занимает достаточно длительное время.Может знает кто-нибудь как распараллелить вычисление этого скрипта,чтобы его обрабатывали сразу несколько ядер?

Answer (score 11):

Необходимо

- понять, что имеющийся скрипт делает
- какие части возможно выполнять независимо друг от друга
- переписать скрипт используя процессы, потоки или что угодно другое для разделения одного потока команд на несколько

Какого-то волшебного слова или директивы `use many cores` в императивных языках программирования нет. Потому что сама программа является последовательностью команд. Одну последовательность только одно ядро CPU выполнять и может. Нельзя одну последовательность команд параллельно разделить на 10 ядер и получить в результате осмысленный результат.

---

Возможно, вам подойдёт и простейший способ загрузки нескольких ядер - просто запустить несколько копий программ, каждая из которых будет обрабатывать часть задач. Например, если вам нужно сжать 100 картинок - вы это можете сделать в одном цикле последовательно либо же запустить 10 программ, каждая из которых будет в том же самом цикле совершенно так же последовательно обрабатывать, но не все 100 изображений, а каждый из процессов отдельные 10. Это позволит скорей всего не очень сложным изменением кода использовать не 1, а 10 ядер.

Возможно, удобнее будет взять какой-либо менеджер очередей: запускается нужное число (более простых) однопоточных программ, которые периодически запрашивают из очереди задачу - и выполняют эту задачу. Соответственно одна задача выполняется на одном ядре, но группа задач может выполняться одновременно разными копиями скрипта.